# Why does this switch statement end the while loop when it's run?

Tags: c, while-loop, switch-statement, boolean

I want this program to break from the switch and back into the while loop. Why isn't it working?

I put a switch statement within a while loop. I think the breaks are interfering with the while loop making it break early. How could I fix this problem?

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>


 int main(void)
 {
 
 bool ON_status = true;
 char option = '0';

  while (ON_status == true)
  {
      printf("enter option 1, 2, 3, or 4.\n");
      printf("Select an option from the menu above then press the enter key:  ");
      scanf("%1s", &option);

      switch (option)
      {
      case '1':
           printf("option1 was selcted");
           break;

      case '2':
           printf("option2 was selcted");
           break;

      case '3':
           printf("option3 was selcted");
           break;

      case '4':
           printf("option4 was selcted");
           ON_status = false;
           break;

      default:
           break;
      }
  }
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: `%1s` will read one char AND appends a nul character, for which you have no room. (That null char may overwrite your bool, it becoming false.)

Comment: Change `%1s` to `%c`

Comment: `while (ON_status == true)` is better written as `while (ON_status)`.

Comment: @john-kugelman I do not believe this is a dup. Firstly it is the reverse/inverse of the dup... and also the root cause is a buffer overflow. Voting for reopen.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Yes you are correct. I checked the memory address of `option` and `ON_status`. Both are allocated in adjacent memory addresses. Null char did overwrite the `ON_status` variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue with your code is that the line

```c
scanf("%1s", &option);
```

overflows the memory in `option`.

Strings in C are null-terminated. So '%1s' stores one character and a null terminator. But your `option` variable is only one character long, so where does the zero (or NULL, NUL, null depending on your naming) go?

In this case, because `ON_status` and option are declared close by in memory it is overwriting `ON_status`.

To see that this what is going on you could print the value of `ON_status` outside the `switch` and you would observe that it was 0.

To fix the problem, I think I would replace your `scanf` with

```c
option = getc(stdin);
```